# Webview causing react-native app to crash on navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The app crashes on multiple Android devices I tested on.
When I go from the welcome screen to a screen containing nothing but the webview tag, I click back to welcome screen and hit login button that has this navigation code on login success, here it crashes before the navigation:

```
const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  routes: [{ name: 'primaryStack' }]
 })

function login() {
 .....
 .....
 if (success) navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
}
```

Here's my webview tag on the webview screen:

```
       <WebView
          // style={{ opacity: 0.99, overflow: 'hidden' }}
          source={{ uri: 'http://192.168.1.6:8000/admin' }}
          androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled
          startInLoadingState={true}
          renderLoading={() => 
            <Text style={[P,{color:color.palette.blue,alignSelf:"center",}]}
            numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">
              Loading…
            </Text>
          }
        />
      </View>
```

My navigation stacks:

```
<NavigationContainer {...props} ref={ref}>
  <Stack.Navigator
screenOptions={{
  headerShown: false,
  gestureEnabled: true,
}}
>
  
  { (rootStore.auth.loggedin) ?
    <Stack.Screen
      name="primaryStack"
      component={PrimaryNavigator}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        screenOrientation: "portrait",
      }}
    /> :
    <Stack.Screen
      name="authStack"
      component={AuthNavigator}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        screenOrientation: "portrait",
      }}
    />
  }
  
</Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Packages:

```
...
...
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
"mobx": "^4.15.4",
"mobx-react-lite": "^1.4.1",
"mobx-state-tree": "^3.14.1",
"react-native-safe-area-view": "1.1.1",
"react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
"react-native-webview": "^11.13.0",
...
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen this [Screen with WebView crashes App during navigation](http://In%20react-navigation%20%3E=%206.x%20use%20%3CStack.Screen%20...%20options=%7B%7Banimation:%27none%27%7D%7D%20/%3E)?

Workarounds:
`<Stack.Screen ... options={{animationEnabled: false}} />` or
`react-navigation >= 6.x use <Stack.Screen ... options={{animation:'none'}} />`

Comment: there's no 'animationEnabled' in options for my navigation version ^5.1.5 but i found stackAnimation: 'none' . is it the same thing?

Comment: It is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

i think maybe there is conflict between react-Navigation lib and webView lib.
i solved that problem by using `opacity = 0.99` in  component.
so if you delete your comment out at that line, that will be solved.

Comment: sadly that didn't work for me! that's why i left it commented out there, so you know i tried that hack

Comment: This worked for me when the WebView component was wrapped inside a <View> tag